# Sunspot-Rails fulltext multiple value search

Tags: full-text-search, sunspot-rails

I would like to do something like this:

keywords ["keyword_1", "keyword_2",...], fields => some_field

The array of values is generic that is why I cannot sequentially call multiple keywords with different values.

Is this possible? I was not able to find it in the API doc...